# loop multiple variables in python

Tags: python, loops

Say I have a thousand variables.
v1,v2,v3,...,v1000, but they are just variables not in a list.

Is there any way I can loop them.

I know in c I can use Marcos.

But how can I do it in python?
Any hints will be helpful.

Comment: An example of the data and the expected output would be nice.

Comment: thousands of variables??? wouldn't it be easier to use arrays? i mean arrays were made to solve this problem..

Comment: You could, but there is no way it would be better than using a list.

Comment: @bakriawad The problem is they are not in arrays or in files. They are just variables in another source code.

Comment: @AlexWei that was helpful, should include in question along with what the variables are or what they look like.. i don't know python but i am thinking you are looking for a way the compiler would look for all the variables there and gets them into a list then execute a loop. try looking for a method that returns all the variables in a code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative way is to use [vars()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars). for example:

```
v1='dd';
v2=32;
v4=12;


import re
re_p = re.compile('^v\d+')

var_list = vars().copy()

for a_var in (v for v in var_list if re_p.match(v)):
    print(a_var, var_list[a_var])
```

Prints:

```
v1 dd
v4 12
v2 32
```

Answer (score 2):

```
v1 = 'foo'
v2 = 'bar'
v3 = '42'

for i in range(1,4):
  print vars()['v' + str(i)]
```

Comment: @taesu Thanks for your answer. I have checked your code have answered my question. Since Marcin give the link of the vars and more formal than your answer. I will accept his as the answer and upvote your answer. Hope you don't mind. Thanks your answer again. It helps.